# Trying to do htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect API calls to api.php with parameters, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/widgetapi
RewriteRule ^widgetapi/(.*)/(.*)$ api.php?action=$1&string=$2 [L]
```

How can I achieve this? I want all calls similar to `/widgetapi/cook/bacon` map to `/api.php?action=cook&string=bacon`. Right now it seems that something is rewritten, but I see white page instead of api.php output.

Apache version is 2.2, rules are in .htaccess, RewriteEngine is On (other URLs are rewritten as intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, this rewrite rule seems to work. White page was actually api.php output because I've written `$items = []` instead of `$items = array()`.

Comment: However you don't need RewriteCond above, that is already taken care by your RewriteRule match.